# API Throttling on photos.get?

Tags: facebook, api, photos

I have an application which pulls in Facebook images from a group to display on the site, with the thumbnails linking back to FB.

This all works pretty well except that now we have more images in the group we're seemingly getting throttled by the API and have to pause 10-15 mins between requests in order to get valid data back.

Is there any hard and fast documentation as to how many requests for photos an application can make without being cut off?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throttling goes thru an algorithm designed by Facebook.  This algorithm is very proprietary and they do not publicly tell people how it works.  In your situation it would appear you're doing a few things incorrectly.

You're not caching the API data (so you don't constantly query the API to death).
You're probably not monitoring the etags (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/627/)

The good thing is your app is monitoring for the error messages from Facebook and self-throttling (which many app devs totally forget and then get their app into a world of hurt by short-cutting/ignoring to do the code for this simple task). Kudos for doing that!!

Comment: Thanks for this super helpful reply. In my defence the original app was written before E-Tags were implemented, but the change is certainly worthy of a retrofit! Thanks!